# Add Barcode into html

Tags: html

It does not work:

```html
<div style="font-family:LBC39W95">
  358853358
</div>
```

or:

```html
<font face="LBC39W95">358853358</font>
```

How to set correctly To reach the result in the picture?
[image]

**I tried with ***

Answer (score 4):

You need to import your barcode font correctly prior to using it. For instance, using Google Font's "Libre Barcode 39 Extended Text" :

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Barcode+39+Extended+Text&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<span style="font-family: 'Libre Barcode 39 Extended Text'; font-size: 55px;">358853358</span>
```

Coincidentally, your barcode sample seems to be a valid UPC-12 / EAN-13 barcode with trimmed leading 0s. So you may also be able to write it so:

```css
.upc-barcode,
.ean-barcode {
  font-family: 'Libre Barcode EAN13 Text';
  font-size: 128px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Barcode+EAN13+Text&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div>
<strong>UPC-12:</strong>
<span class="upc-barcode">000358853358</span>
</div>

<div>
<strong>EAN-13:</strong>
<span class="ean-barcode">0000358853358</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Just noting that this doesn't show up in Edge 121.0.x

Comment: Just tested the above snippet and it does work in Edge 121.0.2277.128

Answer (score 2):

there is some library that can do it in canvas or svg JsBarcode
https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode

```js
JsBarcode("#barcode", "358853358");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsbarcode/3.11.5/JsBarcode.all.min.js" integrity="sha512-QEAheCz+x/VkKtxeGoDq6nsGyzTx/0LMINTgQjqZ0h3+NjP+bCsPYz3hn0HnBkGmkIFSr7QcEZT+KyEM7lbLPQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<canvas id="barcode"></canvas>
```